# Cannot open the directory in command prompt for ubuntu server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy my **flask project** into **ubuntu server** in **aws ec2 instance**.
I connected successfully my computer into ubuntu server and **updated the version** also.

Then I cloned the project using **"https://github.com/app-generator/flask-dashboard-atlantis-dark.git"**
Ubuntu Server is reading my **.ssh folder** where the **key.pem** of aws instance is placed.
but when I tried to go to the directory where **flask-dashboard-atlantis-dark-master.rar** is placed by using **cd** command in **command prompt** following error popups.

**-bash: cd: flask-dashboard-atlantis-dark-master: No such file or directory**

I have placed my directory with flask project and .rar file here,
*****C:\Users\ASUS\flask-dashboard-atlantis-dark-master*****

Please help me in this regard..!

Comment: Sounds like the directory is on your local windows server and you are logged in to the remote ubuntu server on AWS. Try coping the file before login in. This guide might help (Transferring Files Using WinSCP section): https://asf.alaska.edu/how-to/data-recipes/moving-files-into-and-out-of-an-aws-ec2-instance-windows/

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. This link helped me to resolve the problem.